# Why is react-router-dom custom route not working?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I am trying to build an application which involves both the private and public routing, so I am using the custom private and public routes, but the thing is when I'm trying to send the component, it is not being rendered and I cannot figure it out what is wrong.

Here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lkgph?file=/src/App.js) to the sandbox, the entry point i.e the routes [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/lkgph?file=/src/routes/index.jsx) which are handling the public and private routes.

Note: The Custom functional routes are working but not my routes, even if I try passing some custom routes which like h1 or something it works. But not the ones I've built.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use "exact" from Route attribute. Because `<Switch>` check and render the first child Route that matches the location. In this case is "/", and all of your routes contains "/"

```js
 <PrivateRoute exact path={route.path} component={route.component} />
```

And then you must to render the component in the property component inside your array of routes.

This is your final object of private routes:

```js
 const routes = [
    {
      path: '/',
      component: <h1>path component</h1>,
    },
    {
      path: '/write',
      component: <UserInfo/>,
    },
    {
      path: '/profile',
      component:<Profile/>,
    },
    {
      path: '/polls',
      component: <ListPolls/>,
    },
    {
      path: '/details',
      component: <UserInfo/>,
    }
]
```

Because you are using "render" attribute of Route.

If you want send the component without , you should use "component" attribute of Route, but you can only use components, not render HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues

1. You need to give `exact` to your `PrivateRoute` and `PublicRoute`
2. Since you use the `render` prop, you need to return an element and not the component class, so something like `<component />` but custom components need to start with a capital letter so you need to rename that.

[updated example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yearbook-client-md98k?file=/src/routes/private.jsx:467-625)

---

an addtional issue is that for most routes the component is an actual component, but for the `/` route you pass an element and so you need to render it in a different way

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Route attribute "exact" for this url '/'

From documentation:

> exact - When true, will only match if the path matches the location.pathname
>   exactly.

Just read carefully the documentation piece about Switch:

> Switch - Renders the first child  or  that matches the
>   location.

The first child each time will be that component

```js
<PrivateRoute path="/" component={route.component} />;
```

because comparing works by the next algorithm:

```js
'/'.includes('/') // true
'/write'.includes('/') // true
```

But with exact property it will be work by the next scenario:

```js
'/' === '/' // true
'/write' === '/' // false
```

Comment: I have tried it already, you can try checking it. It still doesn't work. Here's the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/yearbook-client-lkgph?file=/src/routes/private.jsx:237-251)

Comment: @RaghavSharma you have to add key={route.path} to each list item and it will work

Comment: you do next thing in private route `(component ...) => return component`, but have to `(component: Component, ...) => return <Component />`